# Correct input went into validation loop at least once after return from sub menu

Tags: c++, validation

I'm current writing a simple application that involve certain menu driven, such as Main Menu > Sub-menu > sub-sub-menu.. etc.
And I put input validation on all of them to prevent input error like,

```
while (option != '1' && option != '2' && option != '3' && option != '0')
    {
        //correction prompt
    }
```

In one of my menu, when I enter its sub-menu, and return back to it. Any input that I attempt to enter will result the system went into my validation loop at least once, given the input is appropriate or not.

My Code:

```
void passengerRecord()
{
    int again = 0;
    char option;
    do
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Please tell me what you want to do." << endl;
        cout << "1. Add Passenger Record" << endl;
        cout << "2. Edit Passenger Record" << endl;
        cout << "3. Delete Passenger Record" << endl;
        cout << "0. Back to System Module Menu" << endl;
        cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin.ignore();
        if (again > 0)
            cin.clear();
        cin.get(option);
        while (option != '1' && option != '2' && option != '3' && option != '0')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Error Input! Please try again." << endl;
            cout << "Please tell me what you want to do." << endl;
            cout << "1. Add Passenger Record" << endl;
            cout << "2. Edit Passenger Record" << endl;
            cout << "3. Delete Passenger Record" << endl;
            cout << "0. Back to System Module Menu" << endl;
            cout << "Your choice: ";
            cin.get(option);
        }
        switch (option)
        {
            case '1':   passengerAddsa();break;
            case '2':   passengerEditsa();break;
            case '3':   passengerDeletesa();break;
            case '0':   cout << "Redirecting back to module menu..."; 
                        cin.ignore();break;
            default: cout << "Exception error occurred!";
        }
        again++;
    } while (option != '0');

}
```

As long as I've enter one of its sub-menu (add,edit,delete), and return to here (either the other function using cin.get() and proceed to return;, or end of function), the next input I enter for this menu will goes into validation loop at least once.
This situation only occurred at second time ++ access to this menu, first time access has no problem

Method that I've tried:
1.) cin.ignore(), its useless and just required me to input more line.
2.) cin.clear(), I see no difference. Probably it has nothing to do with cin buffer
3.) Only run 1,2 method after second time at menu, with `again ++` and `if (again>0) //syntax`, not helping as well.

I've squeezed what I've learned before but no luck, can't find similar problem.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your expectations are to read something from input that's followed by a newline, and expect it to be one character. But before your expectation are met, you have to read a line of text from standard input. That's a prerequisite. Before you can parse what you read, you have to read it, first. One step at a time, and this is what `std::getline()` is for. Using `std::getline()` eliminates the need for all that nonsense with clear() and ignore(). This is `std::getline`'s job: to read a line of input. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: I tried to modify but it seems doesn't work for me, getline() can't receive single char, is there any other solution?

Comment: Never mind, I just solve it by using "int again" to validate whether its first time access, and only run cin.ignore() during first time access. Thanks for your comment, figured it out by reading your first few sentences.

Comment: @LeonSeveron If you solved, please answer your own question in the `Your Answer` box below. Once you're allowed, accept that answer. That helps anyone else who comes across this later, and gets the question off of the "Unanswered" list. *Do not edit your question and post "Solved". It's against community standards, and doesn't use the correct tools.* Thank you! :D

Comment: @CodeMouse92 done, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solve by running `cin.ignore()` only when first time access

```
void passengerRecord()
{
int again = 0;
char option;
do
{
    //menu syntax
    //.
    //.
    if (again == 0) // only run when it's first time access during this call
        cin.ignore();
    while (option != '1' && option != '2' && option != '3' && option != '0')
    {
        //error input correction
    }

    //proceed to sub-menu

    again++; // increment or again = 1; to indicate the menu had been accessed during this call
} while (option != '0');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the only certainty is: if you use cin prior to calling get(), you may need to flush the buffer and clear the flags (example below):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void passengerRecord(){
    char option;
    //Uncomment the below if cin was use prior to this function and not safely emptied.
    //cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');//Ignore with delimiter newline
    //cin.clear();//Clear flags in cin
    do
    {
        //system("CLS");//Commented to display data;
        cout << "Please tell me what you want to do." << endl;
        cout << "1. Add Passenger Record" << endl;
        cout << "2. Edit Passenger Record" << endl;
        cout << "3. Delete Passenger Record" << endl;
        cout << "0. Back to System Module Menu" << endl;
        cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin.get(option);
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');//Ignore with delimiter newline
        cin.clear();//Clear flags in cin
        while (option != '1' && option != '2' && option != '3' && option != '0')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Error Input! Please try again." << endl;
            cout << "Please tell me what you want to do." << endl;
            cout << "1. Add Passenger Record" << endl;
            cout << "2. Edit Passenger Record" << endl;
            cout << "3. Delete Passenger Record" << endl;
            cout << "0. Back to System Module Menu" << endl;
            cout << "Your choice: ";
            cin.get(option);
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');//Ignore with delimiter newline
            cin.clear();//Clear flags in cin
        }
        switch (option)
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "passengerAddsa();" << endl;
                break;
            case '2':
                cout << "passengerEditsa();" << endl;
                break;
            case '3':
                cout << "passengerDeletesa();" << endl;
                break;
            case '0':
                cout << "Redirecting back to module menu...";
                cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');//Ignore with delimiter newline
                cin.clear();//Clear flags in cin
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Exception error occurred!";
        }
    } while (option != '0');
}
int main() {
    passengerRecord();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge sharing! Will try to apply this next time, since for this application I've used another way to solve it. Pretty sure I will come with another menu-drive application anytime soon.